# How to get access to an object which is in a different class while maintaining encapsulation? (data?)

Tags: c#, oop, encapsulation

I'm making a Phone Book console application in c# and It's my biggest project so far :)
I consider myself as a beginner but I would love to improve

I am using 3 classes to create this, here they are:

- Modifications
- Search
- Display

Modifications class is responsible for adding, deleting and editing contacts. Search and Display classes are self explanatory. I also have interfaces for each of these classes.

---

### Problem:

I created a List of KeyValuePair inside Modifications class, like this:

```
private List<KeyValuePair<string , int>> AllContacts { get; set; } 

public Modifications()
{ 
   AllContacts = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>(); 
}
```

I would like to access this `AllContacts` object in my other classes. But I failed to achieve this while maintaining encapsulation. `AllContacts` is like my main source of data. I add contacts in this List. I don't want someone in my main method to be like   `modificationObject.AllContacts.Clear();`

---

### My Attempts:

[ skip this if you prefer :) ]

***My Sad Attempt Part 1:***

-Inherited Display Class from base class Modifications

-in my Modifications class, I created a protected property of type `List<KeyValuePair<string , int>>` and named it 'AllContacts' as a database

-in my Display class , I created a private property of same type as above and named it _allContacts

-inside Constructor of my Display class, I requested a Modification type object named it modObject

-I stated , `_data = modObject.AllContacts;`

-It didnt work, I presume it's because only derived objects are able to get this property?

***My Sad Attempt Part 2:***

-Assuming my assumption is true, I tried to downcast the modObject to its derived class type, Display. Got compilation error instead. Tried to make a protected `GetAllContacts()` method, compilation error.

***My Sad Attempt Part 6:***

-In end, I just made it a public property with a private setter. My application works, But people could still go `x.AllContacts.Clear()` in my main method somehow.

---

### Questions:

- How can I use `AllContacts`object in other classes without breaking encapsulation? Is it even possible?
- Initially, I created a separate class for data and I had 3 other classes (Modification, Search and Display) , its a better design, right? I had same problem in accessing that data object in my other classes.

Thanks :)

---

### Additional Context if required: (currently working application , no methods)

***Modification class:***

```
 public class Modifications
    {
        public List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> AllContacts { get; private set; }
        public Modifications()
        {
            AllContacts = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
        }
....
```

***Display class:***

```
public class Display : IDisplayable
{
    private List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> AllContacts;
    public Display(Modifications modificationsObject)
    {
        AllContacts = modificationsObject.AllContacts;
    }

....
```

---

---

Comment: Hello welcome! Your understanding of encapsulation is on track. `AllContacts` will remain private, just add setters and getters methods for other classes to have access on it. If Search and DIsplay will only read this list, only expose a getter method, this wil not violate the encapsulation rule

Comment: Either you make the AllContacts list public or add getters and setters which sets and returns AllContacts object :)

Comment: What does search and display classes do? If they are related to same content, why arent they in the same class?

Comment: You are over engineering stuff, making classes too small, adding too much classes etc. You are basically asking that you need your private property to be public property. Why define it as a private property at all then?  Make it all in one class and that will be the best option.

Comment: @Djuro Yes it seems like so, all my classes are related to phone book but I am separating mini functions like if they modify the data, or if they just display the data or if they are searching. I should just put everything in a PhoneBook class, right?

Comment: Not everything, but you need special class called Contact, and withing PhoneBook you have private List<Contact>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to declare accessors for a private variable member unless you want to disallow the setter for all others methods but it is more speed optimized to use readonly field than property that avoid useless CPU Proc Calls that consume ticks timings for nothing.

To access it from other classes you must declare it as public like that:

```
public List<KeyValuePair<string , int>> AllContacts { get; private set; }
```

So others classes can read the reference and invoke variables accessors and methods of the List instance like Count and Add but they can't replace this instance reference and thus change the object itself.

But if you want to disallow manipulating of the list, you may implement all wrapped methods you want to expose like Count, Add, Delete, Remove and so on as well as indexer and you can indicate that the class implements `IExumerable<KeyValuePair<string , int>>`.

By this way you can have a strong encapsulation:

```
public class MyClass: IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string , int>>
{
  private readonly List<KeyValuePair<string , int>> AllContacts
    = new List<KeyValuePair<string , int>>();

  public int ContactsCount
  {
    get { return AllContacts.Count; }
  }

  public KeyValuePair<string , int> this[int index]
  {
    get { return AllContacts[index]; }
    set { AllContacts[index] = value; }  // don't declare if readonly
  }

  // if adding is allowed
  public int Add(KeyValuePair<string , int> item)
  {
    ...
  }

  ...

}
```

Comment: implicitly it's still exposing accessors

Comment: Hi, your answer was very comprehensible! I understand that you're essentially just giving away bits and pieces of the object! Although I came to conclusion that I'm unnecessarily creating too many classes, would you agree?

Comment: I don't really understand what you plan to do with classes, but it is a matter of opinion and of design pattern. You can do things in one class or you can create several processing classes that manipulate one data class. It depends on your high design, on the complexity, and on the use cases before all. It depends on how the encapsulated data will be accessed and processed, by what, when, how and so on. So having a data class and some classes to create the data, display the data, modify the data and so on will be good depending on the desired dichotomy/segregation and the entities that act on.